# Messing around with Unity on Ubuntu 19.04, resulted a messed GNOME

Tags: unity, gnome, ld

I was attempting to install Unity on my Ubuntu 19.04 using `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`, but the desktop didn't work as intended, so I decided to undo and redo it. On my way rolling back changes, after log back in to GNOME I got this:

[image: Two title bars after going back from Unity to GNOME?????]

Then after I uninstalled the desktop and `sudo apt autoremove`, I noticed that the title bars returned back normal, but I got this error instead:

[image: Purging gtk3-nocsd returns the original title bar, but makes LD_PRELOAD complains about it.]

Following [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825857/error-ld-so-object-libgtk3-nocsd-so-0-from-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded), it turns out that `autoremove` had removed `gtk3-nocsd` which contains `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`, a file that `LD_PRELOAD` somehow needs, so it was complaining about it. I reinstalled it and the error went away, but those second title bars came back.

I think Unity has messed `LD_PRELOAD` up and I still can't find anyway to address this.

Comment: [UPDATE] I reinstalled the desktop and had done some configurations. And turns out, if I configure one desktop it will apply the same to the others. In this case, Unity had put its configuration to `LD_PRELOAD` and GNOME was using the same configuration file that Unity had modified (causing the dual title bars).

Comment: Different desktop environments should have their own configurations, otherwise they will affect each other and might cause serious problems.

Comment: Yes, but Unity is mostly based in Gnome, the current default desktop, and shares a lot with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

By figuring out GNOME and Unity shares their configuration each other, I logged in to Unity and applied GNOME's configurations. Then I logged back in to GNOME and everything is back to normal!

I could then purge the desktop without losing any components.

Comment: Could anyone suggest for me a desktop that I can use separately (doesn't affect much to each other) alongside Ubuntu's GNOME? (Works under `gdm3`, because I want to set it as default)